# JasperReport viewer JSP WebApp error

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jasper-reports

I am using;

1. Tomcat 8
2. Jasper iReport 5.6 also tried Jasper Studio 6.1
3. Tomcat/lib/jasperreports-6.1.1
4. Tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin
5. Tomcat/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar
6. Tomcat/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
7. Tomcat/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar
8. Tomcat/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
9. Tomcat/lib/groovy-all-2.4.3.jar
10. itext-2.1.7.js3.jar

I have tried to display report in web server;

```
<%@ page  import="java.io.*"%> 
<%@ page  import="java.sql.Connection"%> 
<%@ page  import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ page  import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <%
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "root", "root");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("report.jasper"));
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives me an attached error on page(jsp and report file in same folder)[image: See the error screenshot]

Any idea and suggestion highly appriciated.
I have followed according to [this tutorial](http://www.javaknowledge.info/calling-jasper-report-from-java-web-application-using-jsp/)
Thank you,
Supun

Comment: It seems problem with your realPath

Comment: both test.jsp and report.jrxml are in same folder. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: add report.jasper in WEB-INF/classes and recompile and run it

Comment: add this <%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.*" %> One thing more. Put your all jar files in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/Your-Project-Root/WEB-INF/lib folder. Also please write here the path of report.jasper

Comment: There is no WEB-INF/lib folder, My dir structure is as below;
`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0;
webapps, lib,bin,conf,work, logs and temp`.<br>
My report.jrxml path = `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\reports\report.jrxml`

Comment: All jar files i copied to Tomcat 8.0/lib

Comment: Focus on what application.getRealPath("report.jasper") returns, log it, and try to understand where is me .jasper file? and how can I get its absolute position?

Comment: by the way you can run it by changing code to File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\reports\report.jrxml")) but I never recommend this. Please follow directives that I written in my Answer to organize your project

Comment: also gives the same above error. Anyone can give the complete working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider deploying your application correctly see the answer of @Ghayel

Your problem is that `application.getRealPath("report.jasper")` return `null`, hence it can not find the report.jasper..

Since you insist on working code:

replace

```
 File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("report.jasper"));
```

with

```
File reportFile = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 8.0\\webapps\\reports\\report.jasper");
```

Make sure that the complied version of your **.jrxml** the **.jasper** is there... and the `nullpointer` will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Please always create your project directory in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/your-project-directory-root/ then insert all your jar files my making one in your project root as WEB-INF/lib

In your-project-directory-root you can add html, css, js, jsp etc and add java files to your /WEB-INF/classes folder

In your case:

1. Create your project directory in webapps
2. Add your all images, js, css, html, jsp etc. in your project root directory
3. Add your all jar files in /WEB-INF/lib folder
4. also add /WEB-INF/web.xml (deployment descriptor)
5. Restart tomcat

Cheers!!

Comment: `An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /test.jsp`
`28:             File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("report.jasper"));
29:             Map parameters = new HashMap();
30:             parameters.put("sex","Male");
31:             byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);`

Comment: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\reports\report.jasper. Also test.jsp in same dir

Comment: You are not following my directives. add a directory in webapps folder and put your project files as I mentioned above. when you add reports/report.jasper in your /webapps/your-directory then correct it as File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("reports/report.jrxml")) and hopefully it ran smoothly without any problem

Comment: Supun Silva you marked Petter answer whereas he was referring you to follow my directives. anyway Congrats Petter